# Docker service communicaion using UDP broadcasts

Tags: docker, udp, broadcast, service-discovery

We are building a system with multiple micro services that are forwarded by a gateway.

For service discovery we are using our own solution that listens to UDP broadcast messages from services.

It all work fine on a development machines but when we are running it with docker, UDP communication is not working.

We are using `Microsoft.NET.Build.Containers` to build our images. Service responsible for gathering and distributing service information listens for broadcasts on UDP port `4022`. `csproj` contains port information.

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <ContainerPort Include="4022" Type="udp" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Our compose file look something like this:

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  diag:
    image: "praqma/network-multitool:extra"
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks: 
      - internal

  discovery:
    image: "registry/discovery:latest"
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks: 
      - internal
    expose:
      - 4022/udp
      
  some-service:
    image: "registry/some-service:latest"
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks: 
      - internal
      
  gateway:
    image: "registry/gateway:latest"
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks: 
      - external
      - internal
    expose: 
      - 4494:80
      
  logger:
    image: "registry/logger:latest"
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks: 
      - internal

networks:
  internal:
    driver: overlay
    external: false
    
  external:
    external: false
```

When testing using `nmap`, from container running `praqma/network-multitool:extra` image, we have a port closed information:

```bash
bash-5.1# nmap -sU -p 4022 discovery
Starting Nmap 7.91 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2023-09-14 06:08 UTC
Nmap scan report for test-stack_discovery.1.5fofkkppphmw6xpsygni2ux39.test_stack_internal (10.0.16.15)
Host is up (0.00021s latency).

PORT     STATE  SERVICE
4022/udp closed dnox
MAC Address: 02:42:0A:00:10:0F (Unknown)
```

So all other services fail to start because they require configuration from that service.

How we can diagnose that further? Is it even possible to use UDP broadcast approach in docker containers or we need to move to some other form of service discovery?

Comment: When I was making a post in some places I wrote port `4022` instead of `4822`. When testing everywhere port `4822` is used.